# How is rank determined?

Tags: elite-beat-agents

Rank is not directly related to score as one might initially think.  I have gotten Rank B scores higher than my Rank A scores.  So if it isn't score that determines rank, what is it?

Comment: Scores have a lot to do with combos - you might have chained a higher combo with the Rank B score but hit less 300s (or more 50s) or something?

Comment: @Gwen - I know how scoring works.  Hitting a long streak will get you a huge multiplier, but higher score doesn't always mean higher rank.

Comment: ...That's what I meant? Did you see if your Rank A score had more 300s (less 50s, more Elite Beats, etc) than your Rank B score?

Comment: @Gwen - Sorry, I misread what you wrote the first time.  [IGNORE ME!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMNJuSl91qY)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Score* is determined based on how many notes you hit and how well you hit them. *Rank* is determined only by how well you hit them. S ranks also require you don't miss anything; if you miss but still meet the requirements for an S, you'll only get an A. Since the number of notes varies by song, that means score and rank can be very different between them. As a degenerate case, consider a one-note song. The maximum score would be 300 points, but if you got that, you'd expect an S rank.

- S rank: 90%+ scored 300, no misses, no missed small dots, and passed every spinner
- A rank: 81-89% scored 300
- B rank: 71-80% scored 300
- C rank: 61-70% scored 300
- D rank: ≤ 60% scored 300

(I don't remember if these numbers are rounded up or down.)